# Code not running smooth when switching between workbooks (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code (below) running from a form. It sums values in the given range and pastes the sum of all values to a range selected by the user. The code works well if it is executed in one workbook. But, if I want the result in another workbook and switch between two workbooks it is not running smooth...

Any advice how can I update this code to work properly?

```
Private Sub cmdSUM_Click()
Dim arr() As Variant, i As Long, sum As Double
Dim rg As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim nmr As Double
Dim col As New Collection
Dim output As Range, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rg = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each cl In rg
    If IsNumeric(cl.Value) Then
        If Not cl.Value = 0 Then
            nmr = cl.Value
            col.Add nmr
        End If
    End If
Next

ReDim arr(1 To col.Count)
For i = 1 To col.Count
    arr(i) = col.Item(i)
Next i

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    Set output = .InputBox("Select Range", "Range for pasting SUM", Type:=8)
    sum = .WorksheetFunction.sum(arr)
    output = sum
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With output
    Set ws = .Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks(.Parent.Parent.Name)
End With

wb.Activate
ws.Select
output.Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not running smooth"? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut problematic is the selection of the other workbook. You have to double click and it's quite slow

Comment: When you open the window (from a buttone maybe), call it with (for instance) `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` so that the window is non-modal. It should behave better. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/show-method

Comment: What's the point of the collection or the array? You could just sum your values up of the `Range`

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  when I use `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` the form doesn't pop up.

Comment: @Tom you're right the collection and array is not necessary... Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut of course I used the name of my form. But was not working. I will try again

Comment: Where did you put this code exactly? For instance, you could put this as the macro (Sub) associated with the Click event on a button in an Excel worksheet (clicking then shows the user form).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut now it works! Perfectly! My Excel was broken before probably... Thanks!

Comment: Fine!..........

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following instead

```
Private Sub cmdSUM_Click()
    Dim rg As Range, output As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set rg = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set output = Application.InputBox("Select Range", "Range for pasting SUM", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not output Is Nothing Then
        With output
            .Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(rg)
            .Parent.Activate
            .Select
        End With
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: This code seems to work better, yet the switching between workbooks is weird. I still have to double-click to select a cell.

Comment: @MrZH6 how are you changing between workbooks? Is the first click to `Activate` the second workbook then the second to select or....?

Comment: First I activate the workbook from main panel then I have to double click to a cell. First click doesn't put the cell.address to the inputbox. Maybe this behaviour is normal when selecting another workbook while running macro... I usually don't write such codes...

Comment: @MrZH6 It's normal with modal forms (which are the default).